# Generate Url from virtual field or from value of another field

Tags: keystonejs

I would like to generate a Url in a list in keystoneJS. I prefer that the url not be stored in mongo.

Attempted:

- Virtual field: works, but will not generate raw HTML for the href.
- Types.Url: I get the href format, but I need a value from another field in my model, so it generates the url with undefined.. Example:

```
{ type: Types.Url, label: "Link", default: "[http://www.stackoverflow.com/ask?id=][1]" + this._id }
```

Any help on how to pull this off would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For your second point, `this._id` is not available when adding fields to the model, hence why you're getting `undefined`.

Instead, try using a pre-save hook on your model:

```
yourModel.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.link = "[http://www.stackoverflow.com/ask?id=][1]" + this._id;
    next();
}
```

I'm not quite sure if you're trying to just generate a link in this way every time, or if the user should also be able to add their own link. If the later, you'll need to check if the link has been filled in in the pre-save hook.

I hope that helps and sorry it took so long to get an answer on this!